# Extract an object from a photo

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, background, detection, flood-fill

I am currently writing a program that can extract an object from a photo (by detecting and removing the background).

This program works with user input in the following manner : The user marks with green color the foreground area and with red color the background area. The program then associates each pixel of the image either to the foreground or the background.
The idea is to make it work with minimal user input. A working example can be found here : https://clippingmagic.com/ or here http://www.fembotics.com/cropper/.

The algorithm that I've used so far works by associating a root pixel to each pixel of the image. A root pixel is always a pixel marked by the user (which means it's always explicitly foreground or background). Once all the pixels have their root pixel, all pixels that have a background root pixels are removed (their alpha value is set to 0).

In order to associate a root to each pixel, I'm using a flood fill algorithm.
Each pixel marked by the user is the first pixel of a flood fill algorithm. But instead of changing pixels colors, the algorithm changes their root pixel, making it the marked pixel that started the algorithm. The flood fill stops when a pixel already has a root that is nearer (by color distance) than the current marked pixel.

Since at first pixels don't have a root, the first pixel selected by the user will be the root of all pixels in the image. One side effect of this is that whether we start by selecting the foreground or the background will not give the same result even if the selected pixels are the same (because the pixels will initially be either all foreground or all background).

The problem is that some areas don't get associated to the right root which leaves a lot of stray pixels (spots in the background with a foreground root pixel or wholes in the foreground with a background root pixel). Right now I haven't found a way to remove these pixels. Applying a median blur on the image before processing it seems to help, but if the blur is too strong then the sharpness of the resulting object is greatly reduced.

I would like to know if there is a way to suppress these stray pixels without using a strong blur. Has anyone ever tried to do anything similar ? This is unlike a standard magic wand because the user selects two areas (foreground and background) instead of one, and each pixel of the image has to be associated to one of those areas.

I'm open to any suggestions on how to improve the result of this algorithm. Again, a working example of what I am trying to achieve can be found on the two websites I liked above.

Comment: For alternative algorithms you can search for "Graph cut segmentation".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will search on it.
currently, i have found lot of interesting thing thanks to graph cut segmentation.